# $(x+2)/20=1/5$. What is $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(x+2)/20=1/5$. I have been stuck on this problem and tried various solutions to no avail. Please help.

Comment: Try multiplying both sides by 20.

Comment: Answer is: $42$.

Comment: Please show some efforts-what have you tried so far?

Comment: I should mention that @Kaster's comment is a joke comment (it's a reference) and not actually the answer.

Comment: @Kaster "I always thought something was fundamentally wrong about the universe."

Comment: Haha I get @Kaster now.

Comment: Try changing 1/5 to a fraction with the denominator of 20,

Comment: @Kaster: Great.  What's the question?

Answer (score 4):

$$
\frac{x+2}{20}=\frac{1}{5} \tag*{ – multiply both sides by $20$}
$$
$$
\frac{x+2}{1}=\frac{20}{5} \tag*{  – simplify}
$$
$$
x+2=4 \tag*{  – substract $2$ from both sides}
$$
$$
x=2 \tag*{  – the answer}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Given the expression
$$(x+2)/20$$
Suppose that we knew the value of $x$, for example $x=38$. How would we evaluate the above expression? First we see some parentheses, so they need to be evaluated first. Next, the only operation left is a division, so we perform that next. The steps would be as follows
$$\begin{align}
(x+2)/20&=&(38+2)/20\\
&=&40/20\\
&=&2\\
\end{align}$$
Now suppose that instead of knowing the value of $x$ and not knowing the value of the result of the expression (i.e. the right-hand-side of the equations), that we knew the value of the result, with the value of $x$ being unknown. This time, we are not evaluating an expression; we are, in fact, unraveling the evaluation of an expression. This unraveling requires us to **perform the operations in reverse order**. Consider the equation
$$(x+2)/20 = 1/5$$
If we knew the value of $x$ we would add two and then divide by twenty to get $1/5$. To unravel this evaluation we would take the result, reverse the last step (i.e. reverse the division by 20 by multiplying by 20).
$$((x+2)/20)\cdot 20=(1/5)\cdot 20$$
which looks a bit confusing, so I'm going to replace the slashes with horizontal lines.
$$\frac{x+2}{20}\cdot 20=\frac{1}{5}\cdot 20$$
$$x+2=4$$
Next, we reverse the addition of 2 (by subtracting 2).
$$x+2-2=4-2$$
$$x=2$$
Just to recap, when evaluating an expression we follow the BEDMAS order of operations. When solving an equation (or unraveling an evaluation) we reverse the order and reverse the operations themselves (e.g. a division becomes a multiplecation; an addition becomes a subtraction, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

In general, whenever dealing with a fraction equality such as$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d},$$ remember the extremes rule: $$a \times d = b \times c.$$

Applied to your case, this gives $$5 \times (x+2) = 20\times 1$$ which we now expand to $$5x + 10 = 20$$ leading to $$5x = 10$$ and thus $$x=2.$$

Comment: Down voted because it relies on a trick rather than a concept, and the trick is actually more work than understanding the concept. The math is correct, but in my opinion a bad way to teach an algebra student.

Comment: This is absolutely no trick; one just starts from $ad = bc$ and then divides twice by $b$ and $d$. Oh, and it is taught in the fifth grade in the educational system that I went through. But to each his/her own, I suppose.

Comment: I understand where it comes from, but it is "rule based learning" rather than conceptual learning. If students just memorize that a/b=c/d becomes ad=cb, they have no understanding of the underlying math. Instead, if they learn conceptually that division is the inverse of multiplication, they can derive your "rule" and have a better understanding of the mathematics and better number sense. It may be taught certain places, but that doesn't mean it's a good way to teach, especially since in this case it's actually rather silly to multiply by five on both sides as this just adds an extra step.

Comment: This is Kafka-esque; from the "I have opinions about math" department. *Of course* one does not learn about this out of the blue. Stupid me for thinking OP understands already the relationship between multiplication and division. BTW is it OK to remember that for a quadratic equation x has a certain value, or am I supposed to complete the square every time I'm dealing with such an equation?

Comment: It is fine for you to remember tricks as long as you understand the concepts behind them. What I don't like is the tricks being taught without the concepts. If this person understood the relationship of division and multiplication at the level they should, would they be asking for help on a problem involving division as such? Maybe they do understand, maybe they don't.

Comment: *Sigh*. I'm gonna give this one more try. $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \leftrightarrow \frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d} = 0 \leftrightarrow \frac{ad-bc}{bd} = 0 \leftrightarrow ad-bc = 0 \leftrightarrow ad = bc$. Does this look like black magic?

Comment: I am not saying it is a crazy move. I am saying that I am sick and tired of getting algebra students who try to do things like "cross multiply" or "FOIL" when it makes no sense to just because they saw somebody else do it in a case that looks a little similar. If instead you teach them the concepts behind multiplicative inverses and distribution, they don't make the same silly mistakes since they aren't just memorizing rules and trying to apply a "best fit" rule.

Comment: I really dont understand why it is downvoted so much. I would have done exactly the same thing in this place. There is no "trick" only that we have to move all variables to one side and constants to the other. Isn't the first answer *exactly* the same as this one?

Comment: @SE318 instead of saying " i am sick and tired" you should tell, what's wrong in this solution. it doesn't mean that this solution is wrong, if you feel tired and sick from this rule

Comment: @Kartik - Hey now, stop bringing arguments to a rant ;-)

Comment: @chiranjeev I believe I did that in my first three comments. The "sick and tired" part was added so that baudolino knew that I have first hand experience with students whom learned "rule based mathematics" and are struggling due to the fact that they don't understand the concepts underlying the rules.